# Pre-populating a date input with a pre-existing value with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

at current I have a date input (split into 3 inputs for DD/MM/YYYY) - I'm using setState to update their values. I am now *in some cases* introducing an initial value, passed down by a parent component (`dateInputValue`). I'm not sure on the cleanest approach/ implementation so that if this value exists, it is then formatted appropriately (current format of `dateInputValue` is like so: 20-08-2021) and populated into the relevant inputs?

Any advice on the best way forward to find a solution would be really appreciated.

```
const DateInput = ({ name, onValueChange, dateInputValue }: Props) => {
  const [day, setDay] = useState("");
  const [month, setMonth] = useState("");
  const [year, setYear] = useState("");

  const storedDateValue = useRef();

  console.log("Base date value: " + dateInputValue);

  const changeDate = useCallback(
    (birthday) => {
      onValueChange(birthday);
    },
    [onValueChange]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (day !== "" && month !== "" && year !== "") {
      const dateValue = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;

      if (storedDateValue.current !== dateValue) {
        storedDateValue.current = dateValue;

        changeDate(dateValue);
      }
    }
  }, [day, month, year, changeDate]);

  return (
    <StyledInputGroup>
      <label htmlFor={`${name}_day`}>
        <span>Day</span>
        <StyledInput
          type="text"
          maxLength="2"
          name={`${name}_day`}
          id={`${name}_day`}
          label="Day"
          value={day}
          onChange={(e) => setDay(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor={`${name}_month`}>
        <span>Month</span>
        <StyledInput
          type="text"
          maxLength="2"
          name={`${name}_month`}
          id={`${name}_month`}
          label="Month"
          value={month}
          onChange={(e) => setMonth(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <label htmlFor={`${name}_year`}>
        <span>Year</span>
        <StyledInput
          type="text"
          maxLength="4"
          name={`${name}_year`}
          id={`${name}_year`}
          value={year}
          onChange={(e) => setYear(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
    </StyledInputGroup>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const [intialDay, initialMonth, initialYear] = dateInputValue.split('-')
const [day, setDay] = useState(intialDay);
const [month, setMonth] = useState(initialMonth);
const [year, setYear] = useState(initialYear);
```